# Search XML (XPATH/XSLT) return a path in terms of 'rank'

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to search XML and return the number of the returned search. 
For example; searching for 'orange' in the following list , I want to get back 6.

```
<fruits>
<name>apple</name>
<name>apple</name>
<name>apple</name>
<name>apple</name>
<name>apple</name>
<name>orange</name>
<name>apple</name>
<name>apple</name>
<name>apple</name>
</fruits>
```

I'm trying to construct an XPATH like:

```
/fruits/name[6]
```

And I need that position number to be calculated on the input.

(`/fruits/name[$position]`, where `$position` will be the calculated value of that orange amongst the apples there).

I guess some sort of recursive template (walking backwards from the search hit?) might do it - but I'm struggling to work that out; and maybe there's another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="position">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fruits/name"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <result><xsl:value-of select="$position"/></result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:if test="text() = 'orange'">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Places the position in a variable `$position` that you can use (such as in the line following the variable which will print this result):

```
<result>6</result>
```

Comment: I like this answer the best : I always forget that it is possible to apply a template and hold the result in a variable (rather than directly contributing to the output tree). - nice clean solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of preceding `name` siblings:

```
count(/fruits/name[.='orange']/preceding-sibling::name) + 1
```

Note that if you just want to select that element directly (based on its value), then you can simply do this:

```
/fruits/name[.='orange']
```

However, if you really want to return its position, then use the first expression.

Comment: I was tied between voting this or the other answer as accepted - both short and informative. Thanks for this nice bit of xpath.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is to only apply templates to elements that contain the search string. Then return the path with the positional predicate only when needed. That way the returned XPath will be unique and as clean as possible.

**XML Input**

```
<fruits>
    <name>apple</name>
    <name>apple</name>
    <name>apple</name>
    <name>apple</name>
    <name>apple</name>
    <name>orange</name>
    <name>apple</name>
    <name>apple</name>
    <name>apple</name>
</fruits>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="search-string" select="'orange'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[contains(text(),$search-string)]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',local-name())"/>
            <!--Predicate is only output when needed.-->
            <xsl:if test="(preceding-sibling::*|following-sibling::*)[local-name()=local-name(current())]">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=local-name(current())])+1,']')"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
/fruits/name[6]
```

If the search string was "apple", it would return paths for every `name` element with "apple" in it. If you don't want all of those paths, you can return either the first or last by changing the `xsl:apply-templates`...

**First**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="(//*[contains(text(),$search-string)])[1]"/>
```

**Last**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="(//*[contains(text(),$search-string)])[last()]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.